# Autocomplete-like interface with separate ID field?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, html-select

I'd like to use jQuery Autocomplete to offer a sort of interactive dropdown in my form. However, I'd like to display 2 fields - the ID and the description. While it is easy to output both, I can't find a way to keep the ID and the text you want displayed separate, as you can with a simple html select dropdown element. I want to display ID + Description, and be able to "search" for either, but once it's selected I only want to have access to the ID. How can I accomplish this without specifically parsing out the ID? (I'm open to using something other than autocomplete)

Comment: Maybe this is something you want to delve into: https://github.com/mark-harmon/jQueryUI.MulticolumnAutocomplete

Comment: @Bjoern - that actually seems like what I'm looking for. I'll play around with it, thanks!

Comment: @Bjoern - I ended up using that. If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is something you want to delve into:

- [github.com/mark-harmon/jQueryUI.MulticolumnAutocomplete](http://github.com/mark-harmon/jQueryUI.MulticolumnAutocomplete)

It is a simple extension for the jQuery UI autocomplete control that adds support for multiple columns in the drop-down list.